# pass data between pages with router in vue

Tags: vue.js, router, vue-props

Im using router in vue and I want pass data between my different pages without render the props out. How can I pass the data? At the moment Im doing like this but then I am rendering out both pages on the "HelloWorld" page. I just want to pass the data, not to render the data. How can I do this?

Basically I dont want to render the prop like this (where you can see GOODBYE, just pass the message as data).

[image]

Here is a repo:
https://github.com/reppoper/pass-prop-router

**Helloworld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
    <GoodbyeWorld :msg="myData" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import GoodbyeWorld from "./GoodbyeWorld.vue";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: {
    GoodbyeWorld,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      myData: "hello world",
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

**Goodbye.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>GOODBYE</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      debugInc: 0,
      message: this.msg,
    };
  },
   mounted() {
    console.log(this.message)
 }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Don't include the data in the child component's template and it won't be rendered.  But that seems obvious, maybe you're not asking the right question

Comment: I want to be able to reach ````myData: "hello world" ```` in Goodbye.vue. At the moment I am displayin the whole component Goodbye.vue in Helloworld.vue   I dont wont this. I just want to be able to reach the data created in Helloworld.vue in Goodbye.vue

Comment: You can't use Goodbye there if you don't want its template inserted.  So is the problem that you want to use Goodbye somewhere else but can't get the data from Hello when it's not a child?

Comment: Yes the problen is that i dont want its template inserted. But want to be able to access ´´´´ myData: "hello world" ´´´´ in goodbye.vue

Comment: Then you can't use Goodbye there.  Will you use it somewhere else?

Comment: Yes Im using it as a separete page through router

Comment: Ok, you should use [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) to store data globally, and then you can grab it from any component in the app.

Comment: ah ok. Good point. I go for vuex